# What should I throw if someone requests to remove a non-existent element?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list and I was wondering what I should return from its `remove()` function if the list is empty. I looked in on the standard linked list class and its remove methods invoke undefined behavior when the list is empty. That is not what I want to let happen. Is there an appropriate exception in the standard library that one should throw?

Comment: Apparently the object you wanted removed isn't present anymore, so why throw an exception at all? Otherwise just an invalid_argument

Comment: I would be tempted to just return `bool` like: `bool remove(const Element& e);`. I, personally, don't feel it is particularly **exceptional** to try to remove something from an empty container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throw [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range). Or you might even create a subclass of it and throw your own exception class.

From the standard (n3797):

> 19.2.5.1 The class `out_of_range` defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an argument value not in its expected range.

Comment: I'll keep in mind the custom exception for later, but `std::logic_error` is acceptable. Thanks.